# Database wrapper - Heterogeneous service

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-design, heterogeneous-services

**Problem**

I have 3 databases type Oracle, Mysql, Microsoft SQL. data are the same in all databases.
Is there any way to have 1 database, whatever it is, and store data on it, and have a database wrapper in front of It, that handle JDBC, ODBC connections "Oracle, Mysql, MicrosftSQL". so the wrapper layer "Heterogeneous Services" / "Database Gateway ..etc", receive oracle, Mysql ..etc queries and translate them to the database being chosen and response with the result.

**Result**

So instead of managing 3 types of database and backup, update ..etc. I end up managing one database type, for example, "Hive". but still accepting both JDBC, ODBC connections from different applications.

[image]

Comment: Why do you insist in using `JDBC` / `ODBC`?  Try to convince your clients to use some sort of `ORM` (MyBatis, Hibernate etc.) You'll immedietly get rid of this uggly *low level problems*. (and hopefully you don't get some new *high level* problems;)

Comment: convincing the client to use ORM instead not an option for now. that's why we trying to solve the issue from our side.

Comment: If I unterstand you correctly, you want to execute f. e. MySql queries on Hive. Sure it is possible, but you have to write your own sql translator. The question is, whether it is worth of it. Or maybe there are some third party or open source tools on github. It will be a challenging task.

Comment: I mentioned hive as an example. it could be something else. but yes I need to run MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL queries on that database, which means there should be a translator layer in front of the database, and same time understand both JDBC, ODBC.